# jsonpatch path to update array object

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I am having trouble updating an array using json patch and dotnetcore Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.

The idea is to create an operation that replaces the content of an existing array, which in the backend is a list of objects. I have read on http://jsonpatch.com/ that you can only use pointers to replace array content. This is not optimal since an array might not be properly sorted. So I tried replacing the content of the entire array, but when applying the replace I get an error:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.Exceptions.JsonPatchException: The value '' is invalid for target location.

This would be an example body of the json patch:

```
[{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/users",
    "value":[
            {
                    "name" : "john doe",
                    "age" : 35
            },
            {
                    "name" : "mary jane",
                    "age" : 26
            }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any idea on how to create a body to replace arrays using json patch?

Best regards

Comment: Hi, @Rui, if the answer solved your question, please mark it for helping more people. 
If not, we may be able to continue to explore solutions. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: Hi @MichelleWang it helped indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on the same issue. It's not allowed to use `Repalce` list directly so  my solution is defined `Users` object which has `List<User>`.

```
        [HttpPatch]
        public IActionResult JsonPatchForUsers([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument patchDoc)
        {
            var users = new Users();
            patchDoc.ApplyTo(users);

            return new ObjectResult(users);
        }


        public class User
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int age { get; set; }

        }

        public class Users
        {
            public List<User> users { get; set; }
            public Users()
            {
                users = new List<User>()
                {
                    new User
                    {
                        Name = "michael",
                        age = 10
                    },
                    new User
                    {
                        Name = "Jack",
                        age = 11
                    }
            };
            }
        }
```

It works on me.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is correct that it works. I found a parsing error that was not related to the patch which was throwing the error under the hood.

Comment: @Rui Vaz So glad it helped. :D